# Firebase admin only works with forEach?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I have this code:

```
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("Orders")
  .where("branch_id", "==", elemA.data()["branch_id"])
  .where("create_on", ">=", startOfToday)
  .where("create_on", "<=", endOfToday)
  .orderBy("create_on", "desc")
  .get()
  .then(async (response) => {});
```

And trying to loop over the `response` inside.

This worked using a `forEach`:

```
response.forEach((el) => {
   console.log(el.data());
});
```

Though it did not work using a regular `for-loop` nor a with a `for-of`:

```
for(let i = 0; i < response.size; i += 1) {
   const el = response[i];
   console.log(el.data());
}
```

```
for (const el of response) {
   console.log(el.data());
}
```

Why is this happening? Is it a limitation from `firebase-admin` ?

I'm switching away from `forEach` to properly use `await` inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response is a generic object (an instance of [`QuerySnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html)), not an array. To get an array, call `response.docs`.

```js
for(let i of response.docs) {
   console.log(i.data());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why a forEach only works though?

Comment: @OmarDulaimi Like I wrote in answer, what you get out of promise is a generic object with a result array inside of it. `.forEach()` method is just extended through real array inside of it.